# How can I make my macro buttons work on a copy of the host sheet?

Tags: vba, button

Probably an easy one here:
I have recorded simple macros to copy rows from other sheets into a sheet called "Scenario Builder 1". E.g.,:

```
Sheets("Thermal Drying").Select
Rows("1:39").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Scenario Builder 1").Select
ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

However when I make a copy of the sheet (e.g., "Scenario Builder 2"), the macro won't work as the reference is to "Scenario Builder 1". My novice intuition is that I need to define the sheet that hosts the button so that I can return to it to paste the rows, but my searching/skill level has not resulted in success yet.
Figured some of you could probably solve this sleep-walking so: what code should I use to 1) define the button host sheet in a way that returns the focus there to paste, or 2) to accomplish this task using a different approach?

Please and thank-you!

Comment: Quick question. Where do you want to paste the data? What does `ActiveCell` refer to in your case? Is it the last row or it can be any cell of your choice?

Answer (score 0):

No Need for select/activate:

```vb
    Sheets("Thermal Drying").Rows("1:39").Copy
    ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```